# UIViewController passing in method

Tags: ios, objective-c

OK, real quick question, if I want to pass a view controller in a  method, which would be the correct way(apparently, both seem to work) -

```
-(void)fetchedDataN:(UIViewController *)response
```

or

```
-(void)fetchedDataN:(ViewController *)response
```

EDIT: Here is the Complete Code to clarify things

```
- (IBAction)nextButton:(id)sender {


 activityN.hidden=NO;
[activityN startAnimating];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:activityN];

[audioFile stop];
NSLog(@"HELL O");

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
   Page04ViewController *viewControl=[[Page04ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]; 

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedDataN:)
                           withObject:viewControl waitUntilDone:YES];
}); }



-(void)fetchedDataN:(UIViewController *)response{


if ([self interfaceOrientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {

    [self presentViewController:response withPushDirection:@"fromTop"];

    //        NSLog(@"landscape left");
}

else if([self interfaceOrientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{
    [self presentViewController:response withPushDirection:@"fromBottom"];

    //    NSLog(@"landscape right");
} }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably `ViewController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`...

If you try to pass a `UIViewController` to the second method, that won't work (the compiler will complain) because it can't guarantee that the instance you're passing is of the correct class.

If you try to pass `ViewController` to the first method that will work because the compiler can make the guarantee.

The correctness of the method definition depends on your intentions - without knowing that, neither and both are correct, they are just different...

---

For your updated question, if the method is only presenting the view controller then using `UIViewController` can be considered correct as it is the most generic and flexible option. If you wanted to change the method in future to add other features which require `response` to be a specific subclass then the compiler will tell you that it can't guarantee the class is of the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

This is right:
`-(void)fetchedDataN:(UIViewController *)response`.

Then you can

```
-(void)fetchedDataN:(UIViewController *)response
{
    if ([controller isKindOfClass:[ViewControllerSubclass class]])
    {
        //The controller is a ViewControllerSubclass or a subclass of ViewControllerSubclass your code here
    }
    if ([controller isKindOfClass:[MyViewControllerSubclass class]])
    {
        //The controller is a MyViewControllerSubclass or a subclass of MyViewControllerSubclass your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: The concept of `correct` is always based on context - in what context is it 'right'?

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you want to pass only `ViewController` and/or it's descendants or `UIViewController` and all of it's descendants. `UIViewController` will be more generic way as (I assume) `ViewController` is subclass of `UIViewController` and probably you won't extend `ViewController` anymore. Everything depends on context and if you need to use any specific method/property defined in `ViewController` or you just want to receive any view controller subclassing `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a  UIViewController; use the first method. 
I never heard of the type 'ViewController'. It it your own type? If you always want to be sure the passed variable is of type 'ViewController', use the second method.